# Scheduler.triggerJob does not trigger the job

Tags: java, quartz

I am trying to execute my quartz jobs in tests but they do not seem to be triggered. The 'runJob()' is never executed. No exceptions, no errors on logs. What am I missing? Any ideas?

```
@Autowired
Scheduler scheduler;

@Test
@Transactional
public void MyJobTest() {
    //Create a new Job
    JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(MyJob.class.getSimpleName(), JobGroupEnum.GROUP1.getName());
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).storeDurably(true).build();
    try {
        scheduler.addJob(job, true); //Register this job to the scheduler
        scheduler.triggerJob(job.getKey()); //Immediately trigger the Job
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here are the logs:

```
Starting Quartz Scheduler now
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Started MyJobTest in 20.965 seconds (JVM running for 22.537)
Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@704deff2 testClass = MyJobTest, testInstance = ....
Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@704deff2 testClass = MyJobTest, testInstance = ....
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

Comment: Try adding scheduler.start();

Comment: @user2719361 I tried but it doesn't make any difference. I also updated the question with part of the logs. Thank you.

Comment: See [Example 1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/examples/Example1.html) from quartz doc, they add a `sleep` and `shutdown`

Comment: @user2719361 Yes, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Based on comment suggestion [Quartz example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/examples/Example1.html))

Adding the following lines after the `triggerJob()` made it work:

```
Thread.sleep(2L * 1000L); //sleep for 2 seconds so scheduler has time to fire off the job
scheduler.shutdown(true); //passing true tells the Quartz Scheduler to wait until all jobs have completed running
```